# convert string to json fails in ionic2

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic2

In the following code, I'm try to get `json`. But the returned result contains a "space" after brace open and before close:

```json
{ 
  "address": ......,
  "filename": image.png,
  "price": 12
}
```

In following code if I use `res.json()` it returns error for `json parser` . Instead, if I use `res.text()` it returns string completely. Then, I tried to remove " " space by replace

```javascript
this.http.get(Url)
 .map(res => res.text())
 .subscribe(data => {           
   JSON.stringify(data);        
     console.log(data.price);
 });
```

The log shows `undefined` instead of showing 12.

update when i use `res.json()` the fallowing error is shown.
[image]

Comment: `JSON.stringify` converts the `object` to `string`. You are trying to select the `price` field of `data` as if it is an `object`. I think you meant to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Even if you correctly used JSON.parse(), what you posted is not valid JSON. Not because of spaces, but because of missing double quotes. (and `......`, obviously). Fiw the backend. Make it generate valid JSON.

Comment: @echonax `json.parse(data)` also shows  `Unexpected token in JSON at position 23`.

Comment: @Reza because you don't have a valid JSON as JB Nizet stated.

Comment: @JBNizet the I've test the output of url in [link](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) that was correct also `......` is not in output i used to shortify the content.

Comment: If only there was a simple way to post the actual JSON... But hey, if JSON.parse() says it's not valid JSON, it's not valid JSON. We could explain why if you posted the actual JSON.

Comment: I did some changes in back end and know the actual json is: 
`{ "data": [{ "address":" استان البرز، کرج، کرج نو، کوچه 102، ایران ", "filename":"image3.png", "distance": 2878 ,  "price": 101001 }]}` back end in oracle apex

Comment: Hey @Reza, JSON you have posted is valid. I checked it with an online tool. Still, can you check once replacing address to any English text. And try with `res.json()` only. Also, please check if the new json you are trying if it is valid from an online json formatter tool. Thanks. :)

Comment: @SagarKulkarni I add a photo to main question shows the console log. this is also appear when i using `data.json()` `json.parse(data)`

Comment: At token 23 I can see that the text is not in English. I am not sure but did you try this with an English text script. Like `"address" : "SomeAdress"`?

Comment: Yes I did but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is an object `data`, which contains an array of object:

```
{ "data": [{ "address":" استان البرز، کرج، کرج نو، کوچه 102، ایران ", "filename":"image3.png", "distance": 2878 , "price": 101001 }]}
```

So when you try and console log `data.price` there is no such thing. If you actually want to console.log the price of the item that is in the array you would do the following:

```
this.http.get(Url)
 .map(res => res.json().data) // let's extract the array from the JSON
 .subscribe(data => {           
   console.log(data[0].price) // console log the price of the first (and only item) in your array
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case I made these bunch of code, of course it is not so beauty and looks ugly.

```
this.http.get(Url)
    .map(res => res.text())
        .subscribe(data => {            
          console.log(data);
          this.data=data;
          //if these two lines removed everything fails again.
          this.data=this.data.replace(/\n/g,"");
          this.data=this.data.replace(/\t/g,"");
          console.log(this.data);

          //this.data=JSON.stringify(this.data);
          console.log(this.data);

          this.data=JSON.parse(this.data);
          console.log(this.data.data[0].price);
    });
  }
```

any good and beauty Idea is welcome